# Extracting Unknown Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, Employees and Job_History. The two tables have three columns that are identical: employee_id, job_id, and department_id.

I need to display the last_name and department_id from the Employees table, as well as the date when each employee hits their 20 year work anniversary.

The date when the employees start their work is located in start_date from the Job_History table. The anniversary date needs to be displayed like the format: January twenty-third, Nineteen Eighty-Two.

```
    select e.last_name, e.department_id, count(*) as "20 Year Anniversary"
    from job_history l
    inner join employees e on e.department_id = l.department_id
    group by e.department_id, e.last_name
    having count(*) = l.start_date + 20;
```

Now when I run it, it tells me this isn't a group function. How would I change it to the proper syntax?

Comment: This isn't a code writing (or homework-doing) site. Show us how far you have got and what issues you are having. This sounds like a fairly straightforward task: join the tables, find the earliest date, add twenty years? (Why are the dates in the title 'unknown'?)

Comment: Sorry about that, I accidentally clicked Post You Questions before I completed everything.

Comment: This is wrong: `having count(*) = l.start_date + 20;` ==> `l.start_date + 20` is not a group function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would be counting anything, never mind comparing a count to a date. Adding 20 to a date adds twenty *days*.

This might be closer to what you want:

```
select e.last_name, e.department_id,
  add_months(min(jh.start_date), 240) as "20 Year Anniversary"
from employees e
inner join job_history jh
on jh.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id;
```

The join between the tables is only on emoloyee_id, because you want the earliest start date of any job in any department (presumably).

Once you have the earliest date you can add 20 years, which is 240 months.

You can read about how to format a date as a string [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Comment: Thank you. But when I ran your code, the error "Not a Group BY function" appeared.

Comment: @Tim - as pointed out on your later question, you need to include the employee ID in the group-by; otherwise you'd get wrong results with two people in a department with the same last name.